# Extract Conditional Logic to Separate React Component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

My React app has multiple functional components that repeats the same conditional logic, which I would like to extract to its own component to avoid duplicating it across all the components.

Below is an example of one of the pages that shows the repeated boilerplate code. If the global `window.userPermission` does not contain the value `Page1`, the user is redirected to the home page.

Is there some way to modularize this conditional logic including redirect, while passing it the permissions string (`Page1`, etc.)?

```
import ...

export default function SomeComponent() {

  // begin boilerplate code
  if (
    window.userPermission != null &&
    !window.userPermission.find(permission => permission.id == 'Page1')
  ) {
    return (
      <div>
        <Redirect to="/" />
      </div>
    );
  }
  // end boilerplate code

  return (
    <div>
      <Page1/>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Really easy just wrap your page in a wrapper component and if a value is true return the children or else redirect.

```
import {Redirect} from 'react-router-dom'

const SomeComponent = ({children, page}) => {
  if (
    window.userPermission != null &&
    !window.userPermission.find(permission => permission.id == page)
  ) return children

  return <Redirect to="/" />
}

export default SomeComponent
```

Then use this component like so:

```
<SomeComponent page="page1">
  <Page1/>
</SomeComponent>
```

Comment: This is great. Thanks much! The logic is slightly different from mine, but I just switched it back (if true, redirect; if false, return children). I also added a return to get it to work: ... return ( <SomeComponent page="page1"><Page1/></SomeComponent>)